# Question involving indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a^x=b\,c$, $b^y=c\,a$, and $c^z=a\,b$, then how can I prove that $\frac{x}{x+1}+\frac{y}{y+1}+\frac{z}{z+1}=2$? Thank you. I tried a few approaches but failed and as such there is no work to show.

Comment: This is not true.  If $a=b=c=x=y=z=1$, then your precondition is met.  But then the sum is $\frac32$.

Comment: Yes!But what do you think happens when x,y and z are not equal to 1?

Comment: If $a=b=c=1$, your precondition is met automatically, no matter what $x$, $y$, and $z$ are.  So the sum will not be constant.  For large $x$, $y$, and $z$, the sum will be close to $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out by @alex.jordan, the result fails if $a=b=c=1$. We will prove the desired result, for positive $a$, $b$, and $c$. Naturally, there will be a little gap.  But let's just barge ahead.

Let $a=e^u$, $b=e^v$, and $c=e^w$. (It is more comforting to work with addition.)
Then from $a^x=bc$ we get $e^{ux}=e^ve^w$, and therefore $ux=v+w$.  In a similar way, we get the full system
$$ux=v+w;\qquad vy=u+w;\qquad wz=u+v.$$ 
Add up:
$$ux+vy+wz=2(u+v+w).$$
Divide by $u+v+w$:
$$\frac{ux}{u+v+w}+ \frac{vy}{u+v+w}+\frac{wz}{u+v+w}=2. \qquad(\ast)$$
Now from $ux=v+w$ we obtain $ux+u=u+v+w$, so $\frac{u}{u+v+w}=\frac{1}{x+1}$. Thus the first term in $(\ast)$ is $\frac{x}{x+1}$.  We get similar expressions for the other two terms, and the desired result follows.

Now what about the counterexample! We divided by $u+v+w$, which is not possible if $u+v+w=0$, that is, if $abc=1$.  So the amended question could, for example, specify that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive and $abc\ne 1$.

We look in more detail at the case $abc=1$. From $a^x=bc$, by multiplying by $a$, we get $a^{x+1}=1$. Similarly, $b^{y+1}=1$ and $c^{z+1}=1$. If any of $a$, $b$, $c$ is different from $1$, say $a$, then $x+1=0$, and the expression in the problem does not make sense. If all of $a$, $b$, $c$ are $1$, then $x$, $y$, and $z$ are unconstrained, so the equality need not hold.

Answer (score 0):

Though Andre's answer is completely fine (and better than what I am going to write), assuming you know about [Logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), and its [basic formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities), below is an alternate answer (I am writing this answer as sometime this question appears logarithm chapters of textbooks, of course with additional mention of $a,b,c>0$ and $abc\ne1$):

From the first given equation,

$a^x=bc\Rightarrow \frac{x}{1}=\log_a(bc)=\log_a(abc)-1=\frac{1}{\log_{abc}{a}}-1=\frac{1-\log_{abc}{a}}{\log_{abc}{a}}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{x}{1+x}=\frac{1-\log_{abc}{a}}{\log_{abc}{a}+(1-\log_{abc}{a})}=1-\log_{abc}{a}\quad\quad\cdots(1)$

By symmetry (or *similarly*), we have other two equations for $y$ and $z$. Finally adding all those three equations, we get

$\frac{x}{1+x}+\frac{y}{1+y}+\frac{z}{1+z}==3-\log_{abc}{a}-\log_{abc}{b}-\log_{abc}{c}=3-\log_{abc}{abc}=2$

Note that the restrictions appear in the first line.